# How to copy multiple spreadsheets to new workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that generates multiple spreadsheets. I want to copy those spreadsheets to a new workbook, renaming the sheets as I go, and saving the workbook with the new name.

I've tried to use the following code, but it generates a run time error 9, subscript out of range

```
Dim z As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook

    Worksheets("T_Summary").Activate

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    z = Format(DateTime.Now, "dd-MM-YYYY hhmm")
    wb.SaveAs "C\...\desktop\Transactions Summary " & z & ".xlsx"

    Workbooks("Transactions Summary " & z & ".xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1:BO" & h).Value _
        = Workbooks("Auto Recon 2.xlsx").Worksheets("TSummary").Range("A1:BO" & h).Value

    Workbooks("Transactions Summary " & z & ".xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = "TSummary"

    Workbooks("Transactions Summary " & z & ".xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("A1:BO" & h).Value _
        = Workbooks("Auto Recon 2.xlsx").Worksheets("Reject").Range("A1:BO" & h).Value
    Workbooks("Transactions Summary").Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = "Reject"

    Workbooks("Transactions Summary " & z & ".xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet 3").Range("A1:BO" & h).Value _
        = Workbooks("Auto Recon 2.xlsx").Worksheets("U codes").Range("A1:BO" & h).Value
    Workbooks("Transactions Summary " & z & ".xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = "U codes"

    x = 2
    k = Sheets.Count

    While x <= k
        Sheets(x).Delete
        k = Sheets.Count
    Wend

    Workbooks("Transactions Summary " & z & ".xlsx").Close savechanges:=True

Worksheets("Launch Screen").Activate
```

Comment: Were exactly are you getting this error in your code?

Comment: @DragonSamu The error is occurring on the first Workbooks(...

Comment: Is there a specific reason your only copying `Range A1:BO `? If you just want to copy the `Worksheet` I would suggest to use `WorkSheet("Name Here").Copy`

Comment: @DragonSamu it is a speed issue. Some of these files have over 1m rows and 200+ columns,. As such, I  only want a certain amount of both the columns and rows. If I copy the entire file across, it will copy data I don't need, and will crash the macro

Comment: Then its logical to do that yes. I am still checking but the first "issue" I see is where do you give value to `h`? Its not in your code.

Comment: @DragonSamu h is given a value earlier in the macro (200 lines beforehand), and is based on other criteria. It will always be a whole, positive number, between 2 and 500k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing the code myself this is the problem:

When you do `Set wb = Workbooks.Add` Excel makes a new `Workbook` with the `Worksheet` named `Sheet1` instead of `Sheet 1`.

Thus the following code will fix the problem:

```
Workbooks("Transactions Summary " & z & ".xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:BO" & h).Value
```

You will also need to do the following:

```
Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 3
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
```

`Workbooks.Add` creates a `Workbook` with 1 `Sheet` (on my Excel) to make sure you get the right amount of sheets needed you will have to set `3` to the amount needed.(I assumed `3` based on your code)